# Show webform results on same page

Tags: 7, webforms

i have a `webform` with a lot of fields(i am making some kind of calculator for my needs) and after submit i need to show custom output under my webform.

In `hook_form_alter` i have added custom submit handler 
`$form['#submit'][] = 'common_webform_client_form_1562_submit_handler';`

and after submit i need to show my results on same page.

```
function common_webform_client_form_1562_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
   //some logic here

   //redirect to node with my webform
   $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/1544';
}
```

As i can see i cannot modify or add anything to a `$form` i thought i can add `#suffix` to webform and attach my results but i can't, should i do it with `Drupal.settings` and grab it with `javascript`? or is there another option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research i have found the answer. I did this with `ajax` submit. In `hook_form_alter` i have added ajax submit callback with markup element:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#ajax'] = array('callback' => 'common_webform_client_form_1562_submit_handler',
           'wrapper' => 'form-ajax-node-content',
      'method' => 'replace',
      'effect' => 'fade',);
       $form['markup'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<div id = "form-ajax-node-content">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#markup' => '',
            '#weight' => 2000, //set weight to show markup at the bottom of the form
       );
```

And in my callback i can generate any output i want to!)

```
function common_webform_client_form_1562_submit_handler($form, &$form_state) {
   $output = 'Dummy text';
   $form['markup'] = array(
            '#prefix' => '<div id = "form-ajax-node-content">',
            '#suffix' => '</div>',
            '#markup' => $output,
            '#weight' => 2000,
       );
    return $form['markup'];
}
```